# What are some quantitative approaches to figure out Flow Based Alphas on extremely small lookout periods and does 'flow' play a significant role?

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure

I was pondering over the dynamics of the Market Microstructure trying to couple it with some directional flow based alphas but for extremely small look out periods. Does it even make sense to go for flow based alphas for ultra high frequency(Look out periods upto 100 millis)? If yes then can someone provide some insights on how to approach and figure out these.

Answer (score 0):

there is this paper: Lehalle, Charles-Albert, and Eyal Neuman. "[Incorporating signals into optimal trading](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00780-019-00382-7)" Finance and Stochastics 23 (2019): 275-311.

It explains how to use the kind of signal you have in mind in optimal trading. It is based on the imbalance signe, the last section of the paper gives a lot of statistics, like this one:

[image]